# String compression program not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, compression

I'm trying to create a program that condenses a string to how many characters it has. Just to give my non-programming friends an idea of how compression can work.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to put the same alphabets into a single arrays and other same sets of alphabets in other respective arrays.

The code is not complete, as I lost a lot of data from my HDD and this was all I had backed up on Google Drive. Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks!

```
var string = "twinkle twinkle little star how i wonder what you are up above the world so high like a diamond in the sky twinkle twinkle little star"

var brokenString = string.split("")

var counter = 0;
for (i = 1; i < brokenString.length; i++) {
  while (brokenString[counter] === brokenString[i]) {
    //var eval("array" + counter) = new Array(brokenString[i])
    var array = {
      counter:  brokenString[i]
    }
  counter++
  }
}

console.log(array)
```

Comment: I don't think `new Array(brokenString)` does what you think it does. It creates a new array with one element, and that element is the `brokenString` array.

Comment: Actually everything till that line works exactly as I intended it to. It's the loop that I can't get to work. It creates an element out of every single character of the original `string` and puts it into an array called `brokenString`

Comment: Never mind, now I see that you're not assigning `new Array(brokenString)` to anything. What's the purpose of that line? `brokenString` is already an array, calling `new Array()` doesn't do anything to it.

Comment: What's the purpose of `var array`? You're creating that object, but not doing anything with it.

Comment: Yes, I realized that the `new Array(brokenString)` is useless. And now I understand your second comment as well. Thank you for that!

Comment: Overall, this code doesn't really begin to compress a string. What approach were you going for?

Comment: Your `while` is an infinite loop, because `counter++` is outside the loop.

Comment: Unfortunately I lost a lot of code which is why somethings may be looking like dumb practices. Apologies for that. 

My main idea was to try to have the program give me a list containing the letters in the string and the total number of times that they appear. Do you believe you can help me with that?

Comment: That's not really compression, because there's no way to expand that back to the original string. It's more useful for statistical analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object whose keys are the characters and values are the count of those characters.

```js
var string = "twinkle twinkle little star how i wonder what you are up above the world so high like a diamond in the sky twinkle twinkle little star"

var letters = {};
for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  var char = string[i];
  if (char in letters) {
    letters[char]++;
  } else {
    letters[char] = 1;
  }
}

console.log(letters);
```

Comment: Sir @Barmar, thank you so much. I'm sorry that you had to work through an improperly structured question and its code but thank you for your help! If I may ask, is there any resource in particular that you can refer me to so that I can get better at JS? I've already done online practices at `codecademy` and `SoloLearn`, which don't really teach much. Would really appreciate your input in this matter. Thanks again!